# MySQL id null and some long fancy descriprion null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've have a hard time figuring out why im getting a null result from an php query:

In my mySQL database I have the id defined as: int(11), Null:No, Default: None, Extra: AUTO_INCREMENT,
and some long fancy (it includes all possible text entries with all signs like "$%/):...) description text like: varchar(1000), Collation: utf8_unicode_ci, Null:No, Default: None.

I can easily insert everithing in my table with no problems, but when i query the result via php script like:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM tableX") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // xy node
    $response["tableX"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $xy= array();
            $xy["id"] = $row["id"];
            $xy["desc"] = $row["desc"];

        // push single xy into final response array
        array_push($response["tableX"], $xy);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```

After this query i get: id=null and desc=null (and sometimes - i think when there is only text - i get the normal expected result for description but id is always null). I can clearly see the id in the table and it looks normal, but like I said, after the php script, i get null...

Can someone help me here please?

Comment: array_push(); in this second parameter should be string

Comment: And how can I now create a string from this values that I have? I must obtain the id in the array as an integer... and the description should contain all posible entries..

Comment: You can use 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($response["tableX"], $row['id']);
        array_push($response["tableX"], $row['desc'])
    }

Comment: If I put a column in the table with just an ordinary int(10), no increment, no primary key, I can also get a normal php response... Don't know why there is a problem with the id key and the description...

Answer (score 0):

> If you push an array onto the stack, PHP will add the whole array to
>   the next element instead of adding the keys and values to the array.
>   If this is not what you want, you're better off using array_merge() or
>   traverse the array you're pushing on and add each element with
>   $stack[$key] = $value.

```
<?php
    $stack = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    array_push($stack, array('d', 'e', 'f'));
    print_r($stack);
?>
```

> The above will output this: 
>   Array (   [0] => a   [1] => b   [2] =>
>   c   [3] => Array (
>        [0] => a
>        [1] => b
>        [2] => c   ) )

Found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your intended output is an array that looks something like:

```
array(
     "success" => 1
    ,"tableX"  => array(
                        array( "id" => 1, "desc" => "first description"
                       ,array( "id" => 2, "desc" => "second description"
                       ,array( "id" => 3, "desc" => "third description"
                       )
     )
```

or perhaps:

```
array(
     "success" => 1
    ,"tableX"  => array(
                        1 => array( "id" => 1, "desc" => "first description"
                       ,2 => array( "id" => 2, "desc" => "second description"
                       ,3 => array( "id" => 3, "desc" => "third description"
                       )
     )
```

If my assumption is correct then, instead of:

```
array_push($response["tableX"], $xy);
```

you want the following for the first assumed output:

```
$response["tableX"][] = array("id" => $row["id"], "desc" => $row["desc"]);
```

and the following for the second assumed output:

```
$response["tableX"][$row["id"]] = array("id" => $row["id"], "desc" => $row["desc"]);
```

P.S. you do not need to build the temporary $xy array.